# How to modify a output pointer for debug purpose?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function like:

```
   typedef struct
   {
      bool    x; 
      bool    y; 
      bool    z;  
   } myStruct;

static void myFunction(const myStruct     *pTomystruct_out)
{
    if (pTomystruct_out->x == TRUE)
    {
        /*Do Something*/
    }
}
```

Now for some debug purpose I want to add debug code to set the pointer parameter always to TRUE.
Within the function before the if statement I want to do something like:

```
pTomystruct_out.x = TRUE  /*This is not the correct way*/
```

How to do this in the right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pTomystruct_out` is a pointer, so you have to dereference that for manipulating what is pointed.
You can use `*` opetator to dereference:

```
(*pTomystruct_out).x = TRUE;
```

Also you can use `->` operator where `A->B` means `(*A).B`:

```
pTomystruct_out->x = TRUE;
```

Also, this is not enough because the pointer `pTomystruct_out` is marked as `const`.
You can use a cast to non-const pointer for having it allow modifications.

```
((myStruct*)pTomystruct_out)->x = TRUE;
```

This is syntactically collect, but it may be dangerous to modify the object that is thought not to be modified. Creating a copy of the object and modifying the copy is safer.

```
   typedef struct
   {
      bool    x; 
      bool    y; 
      bool    z;  
   } myStruct;

#if 1 /* debug mode */
static void myFunction(const myStruct     *pTomystruct_out_arg) /* change argument name */
{
    myStruct pTomystruct_debug_temp = *pTomystruct_out_arg; /* make a copy */
    myStruct *pTomystruct_out = &pTomystruct_debug_temp; /* declare a variable with original argument name */
    pTomystruct_out->x = TRUE; /* modify the copy */
#else
static void myFunction(const myStruct     *pTomystruct_out)
{
#endif
    if (pTomystruct_out->x == TRUE)
    {
        /*Do Something*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous answer, the parameter is const, disabling modifications to that parameter. You probably don't want it to be const.

To add debug code, you can make use of macros. You can have a header file contain macros, like seen below:

```
#define DEBUG
```

Or:

```
#define DEBUG 1
```

Included a header with this macro allows you to write your function as follows:

```
static void myFunction(const myStruct *pTomystruct_out)
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    pTomystruct_out.x = TRUE
    #endif
}
```

If you used the latter macro, `#define DEBUG 1` (which I recommend), you can use an if-statement instead:

```
static void myFunction(const myStruct *pTomystruct_out)
{
    #if DEBUG
    pTomystruct_out.x = TRUE
    #endif
}
```

I recommend using `#define DEBUG 1`, because then you don't have to comment out the macro whenever you don't want it. You can just set it to 0.

If you don't want a header file, you can use the `-D` flag using gcc, like `gcc <INPUTFILE> -DDEBUG`.